# How do I do a custom view controller transition where one part is a UIView animateWithDuration while the other is transitionFromView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I can't seem to figure out how to do both an `animateWithDuration` and a `transitionWithView` with custom view controller transitions in iOS 7.

Here's my code for transitioning my views. I basically want to transition from the initial view (represented as a screenshot) to having it blurred and darkened (I dissolve the initial screenshot image to the blurred one and add a dark transparent view atop it):

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    ImageGalleryPageViewController* toViewController = (ImageGalleryPageViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController* fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

    // Add an image view representing the view controller we're transitioning from
    UIImage *fromVCImage = [self convertViewToImage:fromViewController.view];
    UIImageView *fromVCImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:fromVCImage];

    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:fromVCImageView];

    // Create a blurred version of the same image view
    GPUImageiOSBlurFilter *blurFilter = [[GPUImageiOSBlurFilter alloc] init];
    blurFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 2.0;

    UIImage *blurredFromVCImage = [blurFilter imageByFilteringImage:fromVCImage];
    UIImageView *blurredFromVCImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:blurredFromVCImage];

    // Add a dark overlay
    UIView *darkOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:fromVCImageView.frame];
    darkOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    darkOverlay.alpha = 0.0;

    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:darkOverlay];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        darkOverlay.alpha = 0.8;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];

    [UIView transitionFromView:fromVCImageView toView:blurredFromVCImageView duration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
}
```

But only the blurring part works, not the darkening. If I remove the last block and just have the first one, the darkening works fine. I can't seem to have both.

How can I make them both work? I know there's probably a workaround for making the alpha of the blurred images be adjusted, but I want to do it with a `transitionFromView:` for more advanced effects.

Comment: There's a way to implement what you are trying to do without having to use both `animateWithDuration` and `transitionWithView`. In the animated transition, you are supposed to add in both the views of `from`- and `toViewController` before the animated transition finishes, so you can just use the view of `fromViewController` instead of having to add `fromVCImageView`. You can then just use `transitionWithView:...` to add in `blurredFromVCImageView` on top and have one of the options be `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` to do the dark overlay animation in the animations block.

Answer (score 0):

In `transitionWithView:...`, logically OR `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` as one of your options. Otherwise, the dark overlay animation will suddenly finish because another animation is just started. Including this option tells the next animation to begin from the current state of the previous animation.